# NgModel as number in Kendo DropDownList

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

My datasource contains items with Id(number) and Name(string). How I can have in my ngModel values of number type when using KendoDropDownList?

Example
http://dojo.telerik.com/IpUYo

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have number as selected value for ng-model.

You have to create another directive to convert selected value to be number.

```
<select ng-model="model.id" convert-to-number>
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
{{ model }}



(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.model = { id: 2 };
  })
  .directive('convertToNumber', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
          return parseInt(val, 10);
        });
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
          return '' + val;
        });
      }
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```